# BBP algorithm for calculating $\pi$ digits, sequentially

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, pi

The wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula
says
$$ \pi = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{16^k} \left( \frac{120k^2 + 151k + 47}{512k^4 + 1024k^3 + 712k^2 + 194k + 15} \right) \right] $$
In trying to implement an algorithm for the actual computation, I found this: https://literateprograms.org/pi_with_the_bbp_formula__python_.html#sequential_generation
where, in the final part, the author computes the fraction
$$ \frac{120k^2 - 89k + 16}{512k^4 - 1024k^3 + 712k^2 - 206k + 21} $$
which is quite reminiscent of the one cited above, but not the same.
A quick test shows that the first output digits are correct.

I really can't find ideas on the derivation of this second fraction from the original.
Where does the second fraction come from?

Comment: Try replacing $k$ with $k-1$.

Comment: Oh damn, thanks.